# ¿Porqué se reduce el contenedor de mi página?

Tags: html, css

Cuando hago una reducción de la ventana a menos de 500px esta tiene un comportamiento extraño, parte del contenedor hace que se reduzca de forma arbitraria. Intenté encerrando las sections afectadas dentro de un div pero no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo mi css, el cual es algo basico, pero anteriormente me habia funcionado, desconozco el resultado obtenido y acudo a sus conocimientos.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap');
 :root {
  --nav-color: #BE3144;
  --text-color: #f0f0f0;
  --project-color: #45567D;
  --body-color: #343639;
  --text-mono: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 100vw;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcome-section h1 {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

.welcome-section p {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  color: var(--nav-color);
}

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5rem .5rem 12rem 0rem;
  background-color: var(--project-color);
}

.project-header {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border-bottom: #BE3144 solid 2px;
}

.project-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px 0px;
  /* row-gap: 20px;
        column-gap: 0; */
}

.project-card {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  /* height: 470px; */
}

.project-card img {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* background-size: cover; */
}

.project-card p {
  font-family: var(--text-mono);
}

.project-card .project-title {
  margin: .5em auto;
}

.project-btn {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--text-mono);
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 90px;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.project-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  border: none;
}

.project-btn i {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.contact {
  border-bottom: 4px solid var(--nav-color);
  padding: 2em 0 10em 0;
}

.contact-header {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-header h2 {
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-header p {
  font-style: oblique;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.contact-links {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact-btn {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.contact-btn:hover {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.contact-btn i {
  margin-right: .5em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* margin-top: 40px; */
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .project-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Portafolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Works</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="contenedor">


    <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
      <h1>Hi I am Warrior</h1>
      <p>a web developer</p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects" class="projects-section">
      <h2 class="project-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
      <div class="project-grid">
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hXhnBTd/tribute.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Tribute Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hs24SdN/form.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Survey Form<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VxJNvcJ/documentation.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Documentation Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/C19KsMV/trombones.png" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Landing Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/" class="project-btn " target="_blank">Show all<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact">
      <div class="contact-header">
        <h2>Let's work together...</h2>
        <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-links">
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-instagram-square"></i>Instagram</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-youtube"></i>Youtube</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-whatsapp-square"></i>Call me</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fab fa-1x fa-github"></i>Github</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>
      **This is just a fake portfolio. All the projects and contact details given are not real.
    </p>
    <p>
      © Created for
      <a href="">freeCodeCamp </a>
    </p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb3856d9f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Prueba reduciendo el texto del h2, por ahí podría estar el problema

Comment: El error es la clase `.project-header` le estás dando un ancho de 600px, por eso se desborda, deberías usar unidades responsivas

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no se reduce el contenedor. Lo que pasa es que  cuando un objeto sobre sale de su contenedor, el navegador muestra todo ese objeto que sobresale. Esto hace el navegador si es que el contenedor no tiene la clase `overflow: hidden`. La @media Queries muestra el contenido correcto, y el navegador muestra el contenido completo. Es algo confuso pero es así.

La solución es darle un ancho del 100% al **h2 `welcome-section`**.

También modifique un poco el título h1 (`welcome-section h1`).

Así estos elementos son responsivas acomodándose en todos las @media Queries.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap');
 :root {
  --nav-color: #BE3144;
  --text-color: #f0f0f0;
  --project-color: #45567D;
  --body-color: #343639;
  --text-mono: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 100vw;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcome-section h1 {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

.welcome-section p {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  color: var(--nav-color);
}

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5rem .5rem 12rem 0rem;
  background-color: var(--project-color);
}

.project-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border-bottom: #BE3144 solid 2px;
}

.project-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px 0px;
  /* row-gap: 20px;
        column-gap: 0; */
}

.project-card {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  /* height: 470px; */
}

.project-card img {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* background-size: cover; */
}

.project-card p {
  font-family: var(--text-mono);
}

.project-card .project-title {
  margin: .5em auto;
}

.project-btn {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--text-mono);
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 90px;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.project-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  border: none;
}

.project-btn i {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.contact {
  border-bottom: 4px solid var(--nav-color);
  padding: 2em 0 10em 0;
}

.contact-header {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-header h2 {
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-header p {
  font-style: oblique;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.contact-links {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact-btn {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.contact-btn:hover {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.contact-btn i {
  margin-right: .5em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* margin-top: 40px; */
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .project-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Portafolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Works</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="contenedor">


    <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
      <h1>Hi I am Warrior</h1>
      <p>a web developer</p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects" class="projects-section">
      <h2 class="project-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
      <div class="project-grid">
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hXhnBTd/tribute.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Tribute Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hs24SdN/form.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Survey Form<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VxJNvcJ/documentation.jpg" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Documentation Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="project project-card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/C19KsMV/trombones.png" alt="" class="project-img">
          <p class="project-title"><span class="code"><</span>Landing Page<span class="code"> /></span></p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/" class="project-btn " target="_blank">Show all<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact">
      <div class="contact-header">
        <h2>Let's work together...</h2>
        <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-links">
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-instagram-square"></i>Instagram</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-youtube"></i>Youtube</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fa-brands fa-1x fa-whatsapp-square"></i>Call me</a>
        <a href="" class="contact-btn"><i class="fab fa-1x fa-github"></i>Github</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>
      **This is just a fake portfolio. All the projects and contact details given are not real.
    </p>
    <p>
      © Created for
      <a href="">freeCodeCamp </a>
    </p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb3856d9f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```